# How to rename Bulk files in GitHub or RDi

Tags: git, github, ibm-rational

We are trying to use GitHub for IBMi code , one of the problem that we are facing is to rename bulk files.
We are trying to build a master branch with all IBMi related source files and have them renamed with appropriate type and attribute.
Eg -
TESTPGM1.RPGLE - Rename as TESTPGM1.MODULE.RPGLE
TESTPGM2.RPGLE - Rename as TESTPGM.SRVPGM.RPGLE

Is there a quick way to rename all files using above format ?
We have around ~25K files with a combination of PGM , MODULE, SRVPGM, PF, LF etc.

As of now we are pushing all these 25K files from RDi to Git using iProject , is there an option to rename bulk files directly in iProject before we push to GitHub ?
We do see an option to rename in RDi but that is one file at a time.

Answer (score 0):

The [IBM i  RNM command](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.2?topic=ssw_ibm_i_72/cl/rnm.html) would not allow bulk rename indeed.

I would rather push everything to GitHub, clone it in a different OS, just to do the rename:

```
for file in *.RPGLE ; do mv "$file" "$(basename $file RPGLE)MODULE.RPGLE"; done
```

Add, commit and push, then sync back in your original IBMi environment.